# (Row, Column) : Value to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataSet in the Following Format coming from a rester Service

```
{'C': {('x', 'Active'): 1, ('x', 'Ready'): 1, ('y', 'Active'): 1, ('y', 'Ready'): 1, ('z', 'Active'): 1, ('z', 'Ready'): 2}}
```

and the Excepted Out I Want is

[image]

But when i try to load data in DF it Loads the Key i.e (Row,Column) as Index

Comment: [`df.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)? the default value is `level=-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
pd.Series(data['C']).unstack()
```

Output:

```
   Active  Ready
x       1      1
y       1      1
z       1      2
```

Comment: as I understand, `data` is just a dictionary.

Comment: ohh yes, my bad. :P

Answer (score 1):

Another way; Apply pd.DataFrame and drop multiindex columns

```
 df=pd.DataFrame(data).unstack()
 df.columns=df.columns.droplevel()


      Active    Ready
   x    1        1
   y    1        1
   z    1        2
```